# TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

When I run rubocop on a file, I get the following warning:

```
(Using Ruby 2.5 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
```

I added the following on `.rubocop.yml` file:

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.5.8
```

Still the warning is not going away. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Had same issue, added the

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.X
```

to my `.rubocop.yml` file and it did nothing, error was still showing up.

Turns out I had a syntax error, I was missing a `}` , once I added it rubocop was able to properly go through my file and find/fix the usual offenses. Have a great day guys!

Answer (score 2):

This error was resolved for me by fixing a syntax error in the file.

Answer (score 2):

you can fix it by adding the following to your .rubocop.yml

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 3.1.x
```

Answer (score 0):

The config file should be named `.rubocop.yml` (dot in front).

Comment: Sorry I misspelled it. I do have the dot in front.